# MS SQL Server query which split to other table columns

Tags: sql, query, ms-sql

I have two tables:

`table1`:

```
Manager | USER 
--------+------
John    | Tom  
John    | David
John    | Marry
James   | Henry
```

`table2`: Now is empty, but must be like this:

```
Manager | User1 | User2 | User3
--------+-------+-------+-------
John    | Tom   | David | Marry
James   | Henry | null  | null
```

Is it possible?

Comment: its certainly possible, but your constraints matter. personally I'd write a sproc that returns all the employees from table1 for a given supervisor. then a cursor over the distinct list of supervisors would let you get all the subordinates and insert them into the new table. There are probably ways to do it with just select code, but your (poorly designed) tables will make that more difficult. I would recommend you stick with the table1 design and avoid the table2 design, as it breaks second normal form.

Comment: If you just need to generate a report in that format to a temp table or something, look into `SELECT COALESCE` syntax as I've generated reports in SQL Server as you describe just for a report but I'd not do this for a permanent table design but that should get you started. Check out dba.stackexchange.com as well.

Comment: Yes, you just query and add to a temporay table.. You'll need to share what you've tried so we can help based upon your existing code :)

Answer (score 0):

If `table2` structure is fixed as you showed you can insert your expected result into it by a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (Manager, User1, User2, User3) 
SELECT
  Manager,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seq = 1 THEN [USER] END) AS User1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seq = 2 THEN [USER] END) AS User2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seq = 3 THEN [USER] END) AS User3
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Manager ORDER BY [USER]) AS seq
  FROM table1) t
GROUP BY
  Manager;
```

But, If `table2` structure is not fixed you need to use Dynamic SQL.